# VS 2012 - Warnings when loading a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I open my solution I get the following message twice:

> Projects have recently been added to this solution. Do you want to get them from source control?

And then:

> One or more projects in the solution could not be loaded correctly. Please see the output window for details

In the output all I see is:

> Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read.

I followed one post that said to set the `SccNumberOfProjects` to be equal in all `Global\GlobalSection` in the `.sln file`, but I still get the message.

1. Does someone know what causes these messages to appear?
2. Where is the Visual Studio 2012 sln load log located?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two problems.

1. The project has the source control reference like TFS or SVN tortoise.
   if you dont need the source control then you can permanently removed on the option in the warning while first loading the project.
2. You system is missing some libraries file to load the project.Try enabling nuget to restore.

Comment: Thanks. 1. I need TFS 2. Can I see it somewhere in the log?

Comment: if you need TFS then open visual studio and connect to Team TFS from Team>Connect to the Team Foundation Sever. And Open your solution after that.